# Is it possible to use insert for a ruby has_many array?

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model

I'm trying to manage adding and deleting instances of a Ruby model that must remain in order. For example, chapter has many paragraphs.

Ideally, I would like to leverage an ordered bunch of elements that allow inserting or deleting at a specific index, instead of just at the end. While Ruby treats the has_many relationship like an array, I don't know what would happen to validation for creating the relationship if a method like array.insert worked. I can't find any documentation on the ActiveRecord pages about that use case (adding directly to the has_many/chapter.paragraphs array with insert), so I'm inclined to believe it doesn't exist natively.

Is there a native way like this already, or should I just create an order field and update it iteratively when appropriate?

Comment: I don't think there's a native way to do it. I would also question whether it even makes sense to have each record track its own 'order'. Because changing the order requires you to update a bunch of records. In this case I think leveraging a more NoSQL approach is better - storing the ordered array of record IDs in a single column (say "user items order" or what have you) - maybe serialized JSON, or maybe the JSON array datatype depending on if your DB supports it

Comment: You may want to use the [`acts_as_list`](https://github.com/brendon/acts_as_list) gem or [something similar](https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Sortables) to add this behavior.